# Laravel middleware one time authorization for route groups

Tags: laravel-5, authorization

I am designing some part of system in Laravel 5. It is expected to behavior as described below.

1. User gets unique url. It could be provided in email, but that will not matter.
2. He clicks it, and gets logged in with some temporary token (for a session lifetime), that gives him possibility to access all the urls in allowed route group, ex. `account/*`, but if he wants to reach other restricted urls, then he is asked to authorize with his username/password.
3. If he is already authorized, token login makes no effect for him.

My question is about possibility to do something like that in Laravel out of box. I know there are some middleware services, but I'm not sure if default Guard behavior will not need to be changed to work as I expect.
I used to work with Symfony before, and there it is solved by firewalls by default, so maybe also in Laravel there is prebuilt solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can absolutely doing this use laravel, here is an example code not tested,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if (preg_match('account', $request->route()->getName()) { //if url is under account, you can get route info from $request->route();
            if (!session()->get($token)) { // if not have valid token
                if ($request->ajax()) {
                    return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
                } else {
                    return redirect()->route('admin.login.index',['referrer'=>urlencode($request->url())]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('admin.login.index',['referrer'=>urlencode($request->url())]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

then from your route just add middleware auth to your group, this is a way to define you request in on middleware, laravel 5.2 support mutiple middleware.